# SMS REST Service?

Tags: api, rest, sms

I've got an application that does some work then hits an URI callback once the work is done.

For testing, I'd like to send an SMS to my cellphone.

Something like http://www.jonskeetistheman.com/SMSSend.aspx?phone=4255555555&msg=supdawg

Are there any REST based SMS services (free) that ya'll can recommend?

Comment: lol Btw what's your **final** solution? I'm interested in this myself..

Comment: I ended up using Clickatell and paying for it. It was like $20 for more than enough sms messages.

Comment: you mean $20 a month for 700 SMSes a month? That's not particularly cheap I think..

Comment: They might have changed their plan, but back when I asked this question '09, I was able to bulk buy SMS without a monthly subscription.

Comment: what was your cost at that time per sms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about free one.

the one I use is clickatell which has the exact same interface (although on an ever so slightly different domain), and costs a few cents per sms.

Answer (score 4):

It's not free, but it *is* cheap: http://www.twilio.com/sms/

Apparently it's all the rage lately.

Comment: And furthermore it doesnt support many countries, plus doesn't support senderid

Answer (score 3):

The only free one I know is from [Zeep Mobile](http://www.zeepmobile.com/).

This post from [killerapi](http://killerapi.blogspot.com/2011/11/free-sms-api-zeepmobile.html) explains the catch. Basically it embeds ads, and is more troublesome to use.

Paid SMS APIs are plenty: Nexmo, Hoiio, Twilio.

Comment: Zeep Mobile on Signup: You will receive an email with activation instructions as soon as a spot becomes available. Wait time is currently 3 days.

Answer (score 2):

[Zeep Mobile](http://www.zeepmobile.com/) offers a free SMS service with a Short Code

Answer (score 1):

www.voxox.com -

Free and offers a wide variety of services, SMS is just one of them.