# Sending SMS message via private frameworks / APIs

Tags: iphone, ios, sms, iphone-privateapi

I have a very quick turnaround for a kiosk style app for a client. It will not be placed on the AppStore, hence my query about private frameworks.

Is there a way to send an email or SMS automatically without getting the user to hit a 'send' button. I want to send it in the background of an app if possible.

Any information would be appreciated.

Cheers
Niall

Answer (score 1):

U may try CTMessageCenter.
U can send SMS without user interation. Only in code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this next time I need it. The project has sadly finished!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about private API in iOS, but there are a number of SMS services that you can use. Here's a thread on that topic:

[SMS REST Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480661/sms-rest-service)